# Cairo-dock transparency issues x2go

Tags: cairo-dock, transparency, x2go

I installed cairo-dock on lubuntu 16.04.  It works well, except that every time the dock shows, instead of having pure transparency around the dock, it wipes a patch out of my windows around the dock; acting as though the only thing under the dock is the desktop.  I am running through x2go.

I have tried matacity and xwfm.

Comment: I am having a similar issue where my terminal transparency just shows up as black background in x2go.  Can't find any info on this.

Comment: @YoussefG., it appears that x2go is unable to send over transparency...  I'm not quite sure why.